# What's the difference between <head> and <asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" ...>?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

This may be a newbie question, but i'm pretty new to asp.net & C# etc.

I'm working with an ASP.net website, and I'm curious about the structure of it (after automatically creating a web project), specifically the following:

I see that in Default.aspx , I have a tag like this:

```
<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
</asp:Content>**strong text**
```

But in Site.master, I have this:

```
<head runat="server">
*etc*
</head>
```

So where would I put code if I wanted to include JavaScript code to run, on page load?

Comment: On every page that uses that master file, or just on Default.aspx? Btw, if you want to run JavaScript on page load, then you can put that JavaScript at the bottom of the page (which aids page performance).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe you can put your code in any of them. The first one is for adding code or script used by all content pages(that using this master page file) while the second one is if you want to to add script or code from content pages(that should be used only for this specific page)

```
//in the Master page, the content here is used by all content pages
<head runat="server">
*etc*
</head>
```

and

```
//this is specific to the content page that use it. This section needs to be supplied in content pages
<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
</asp:Content>
```

That section needs to be supplied in each content page and it will be exclusive to that page - no other page can use the script in that section

Answer (score 6):

*asp:Content ID="HeaderContent"* is a content region. Anything within that tag will get embedded in the associated ContentPlaceHolder in the master page when it is generated.

*head* is a standard html markup, indicating the page head elements. Typically, the HeadContent placeholder is inside the *head* tag on the master page.

Answer (score 1):

The head element, container for all the head elements, must use a title for the document. Some other elements it can include: style, base, link, meta, script, noscript.

The asp: Content ID = "HeaderContent" is a content element of the master page.
Have a look at the Plugging in Content part of the following link for detailed information on this: http://odetocode.com/articles/419.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think you asked when you want to use JavaScript where you put JS in your code.You can put anywhere you wish in asp side between script block such as:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
     <script type="text/javascript">
        function Onclick(){
             //some codes
        }
     </script>
</asp:Content>
```

or

```
    <head runat="server">
     <script type="text/javascript">
        function Onclick(){
             //some codes
        }
     </script>
   </head>
```

Also you can put JS outside this tag. You only should use  tag.